# Choppy animations in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, canvas, svg

My canvas animation is smooth as ice in chrome, but choppy as a bad haircut in firefox. The strangest thing is, it's not even a complex calculation. Does anyone see anything wrong (performance related) with my code that could cause this slowdown?

Here it is on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wu5Jh/

And here it is for SO:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //vars
    var x = 20,
            y = 20,
            pi = Math.PI,
            width,
            height,
            complete = 100,
            refreshInterval,
            ctx;

    // computed vars
    function init() {
      ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
      width = $("#canvas").width();
      height = $("#canvas").height();  
        center = [width/2, height/2];
      refreshInterval = (function doSetTimeout(){
            draw();
            setTimeout(doSetTimeout, 30);
            })();
        };

    function circle(x,y,r) {

        // Draw the growing circle
        ctx.fillStyle = "#09f";
      ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y); // center of the pie
      ctx.arc(
            x, 
            y, 
            r, 
            -2*pi*complete/100 + pi*1.5,
            -pi*.5,
            true
        );
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

        // Draw the cutout
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.beginPath();  
        ctx.arc(x,y,r/2,0,pi*2,true); 
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function clear() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    function timeCheck(){
        if (complete>0){
            complete -= 1;
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(refreshInterval);
        }
    }

    function draw() {
      clear();
      circle(x, y, 20);
        timeCheck();
    }

    init();

});
```

I was hoping to avoid a flash animation or gif, but I might have no choice.

Thanks!

Comment: looks good to me on Firefox 3.6.12

Comment: Really? It chops up for me at about 3 points in 3.6.13, PC

Comment: Consider that it heavily depends on your computer specification and current load.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I just restarted and am using a quadcore, and still get choppiness. I mean, maybe I exaggerate in its amount, but it's clearly smoother in chrome.

Comment: I have some animation in FF that also seems choppy!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see any problems and I am using Chromium 8 and Firefox 3.6.13 on Linux.

However, if you still want suggestions for micro optimizations, then you can make things like `-2*pi/100`, `1.5*pi`, and `.5*pi` as their own constants. Also, this is just a guess, but using `"copy"` instead of `"xor"` for `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` might be faster. You could also store the arc angle that is computed for the first arc drawn and use it for the second as well rather than just having it draw a full circle.